# Retaining Control/Elements values changed via Client side on postbacks

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am using Jquery AJAX in one of my applications with ASP.NET 4.0. Its a web application.
I have used Server side coding + Client side coding aproach i.e. using Jquery, JS and AJAX.

I have some controls which are wrapped in div element and I make them hide/show via client side index change event of dropdownlist.

When a postback occurrs due to server side validation or by any other instance, the divs are retaining there old values which are their initial state. for example: the div is visible first time and I hide it via index change of dropdownlist at client, so when postback occurs Its visible again though it should be hidden.

I have used hiddenfield to store the value and show/hide div according to the value via Hiddenfield in jquery document.ready event.

Now, I wanted to ask that Is there any other approach of getting the desired result. I am expecting some standard approach to do that as nowadays almost all applications are client and AJAX enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to reload the whole page, you have to store the state somewhere. AJAX allows you to reduce/eliminate full reloading of the page, so it provides the illusion of preserving state.

ASP.Net (I'm assuming web forms from the question) can "remember" some values (such as the `Visible` property of a `div`) by putting attributes in `ViewState`. This usually requires a full postback or an `UpdatePanel` (both of which are less than ideal but do work).

### Other Alternatives

- Hidden fields are fine for many things.
- Cookies work in select cases (keep them small--remember they get sent with every request!)
- Local storage in the web browser is great when you want to store client-side values that the server doesn't need to know much/anything about.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Medora.. I have used Viewstate too but Hiddenfield seems good but I want some standard way of maintaining those as I think there should be something which do the trick instead of using hiddenfield as a HACK..

Comment: Why is it a hack? assuming that another method isn't a better fit, it's a valid way of maintaining state on a page.

Comment: Ya. I understand but I think there should be an implicit way of doing this. We are doing this explicitly via hiddenfield. for e.g. there is a implicit mechanism of retaining the value via viewstate on postback i.e. we don't have to write any code for it and .NET automatically doing for us.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for the answers.. I think we need to use Hiddenfields only and I don't think that there is an implicit way.. :)